# How to pass dictionary variable as commandline argument to the script

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary with (key = value) and i want to pass that dictionary object as command line value to python script. Suppose Dictionary name is D and script is test.py then problem statement is

i want to execute it as test.py D and retrive the key value inside test.py script.

Comment: You cant pass a dictionary. You can use a serialized form (`str`) of a dictionary and de-serialize in your script.

Comment: could you please give an example

Comment: How do you intend to run the script?

Comment: i hav a file as below                                                                                                                                                                                       licensen =  ac                                                                                                    host = xyz                                                                                                                                              Now i want those value inside my script test.py so inside my script i should able to initialize variables with dictionary values